# Break from try/catch block

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

Is this possible in PHP?

```
try {

  $obj = new Clas();

  if ($obj->foo) {
    // how to exit from this try block?
  }

  // do other stuff here

} catch(Exception $e) {

}
```

I know I can put the other stuff between `{}`, but that increases indenting on a bigger code block and I don't like it :P

Comment: `throw('Get me out of here!')` will jump out. but that's not exactly nice.

Comment: can't you just use else after the if?

Comment: @MattyF - +1, sounds like an answer to me !

Comment: I can't see any reasonable use of this? Is it just me?

Comment: No. I already have the try thing between two IFs, and I don't want more curlies :(

Comment: `if(!isset($obj->foo)){ do other stuff }` and you know that you can use isset(), if all your doing is seeing if a property of an object is set, no need for ugly try / catch blocks.

Comment: @adeneo - ah sorry for thinking in absolute same way :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld - This is'nt North Korea, feel free to think the same as me whenever you like !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try
{
    $object = new Something();
    if ($object->value)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
     // handle exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 25):

With a [goto](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) of course!

```
try {

  $obj = new Clas();

  if ($obj->foo) {
    goto break_free_of_try;
  }

  // do other stuff here

} catch(Exception $e) {

}
break_free_of_try:
```

Comment: this answer makes me feel both terrified and powerful.

Comment: It's just powerful. Nothing wrong with "goto" - it's an old myth. Many of us programmers are waiting for the industry to realize that the Dijkstra debate is over and there's nothing wrong with a direct jump if you know what you're doing.

Comment: Assembly implements goto BTW, meaning it's low-level, native, therefore perfectily legitimate to use if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Using `goto` in a high level language to control the flow will lead to spaghetti code and bugs and big headaches for the people that will try to maintain the code in the future (*even for the same person that wrote the `goto`'s*), and if you do it once in a small function you’ll do it again and multiple times in big functions. Never use `goto`, even in `C`, there is no need to use `goto`. In Assembly there is no `goto`, there is the `jmp` instruction mostly, which of course if what the `goto` does under the hood and this is how Assemply and machine code works, using jumps and calls.

Comment: Christos, you seem to be operating under the false assumption that my code isn't already spaghetti.

Comment: The Dark Side of the Force is a pathway to many abilities some consider to be unnatural...

Answer (score 13):

Well, there is no reason for that, but you can have fun forcing an exception in your `try` block, stopping execution of your function.

```
try {
   if ($you_dont_like_something){
     throw new Exception();
     //No code will be executed after the exception has been thrown.
   }
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo "Something went wrong";
}
```

Comment: Consider throwing a specific subclass of Exception, rather than top level Exception object. Then, add catches for the various possibilities. Similar to Dan's comment.

Comment: This causes performance losses if you're doing this a lot.

Answer (score 7):

I also faced this situation, and like you, didn't want countless if/else if/else if/else statements as it makes the code less readable.

I ended up extending the Exception class with my own.  The example class below was for validation problems that when triggered would produce a less severe 'log notice'

```
class ValidationEx extends Exception
{
    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return __CLASS__ . ": [{$this->code}]: {$this->message}\n";
    }
}
```

In my main code I call it;

```
throw new ValidationEx('You maniac!');
```

Then at the end of the Try statement I have

```
        catch(ValidationEx $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }
        catch(Exception $e){ echo $e->getMessage(); }
```

Happy for comments and criticisms, we're all here to learn!

Comment: but it just makes no sense to have two catch blocks here? Just one, `catch(Exception $e){ echo $e->getMessage(); }` will do exactly the same?

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't you just do like this?

```
try{

  $obj = new Clas();

  if(!$obj->foo){
  // do other stuff here
  }


}catch(Exception $e){

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In php 5.3+ the nice thing about using exceptions with a try catch block, is that you can make your own Exceptions and handle them how and when you want. See: [Extending Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php)

```
class OtherException extends Exception 
{
    //...
}
```

You can then catch specific exceptions or use `if ($e instanceof OtherException)` within your `catch \Exception` block to determine how you want to handle the exception(s).

1. Handled Example: http://ideone.com/ggz8fu
2. Unhandled Example: http://ideone.com/luPQel

```
try {
    $obj = (object) array('foo' => 'bar');
    if ($obj->foo) {
        throw new OtherException;
    }
    /* do stuff */
} catch (OtherException $e) {
    /* do other stuff here and handle exception */
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($e instanceof InvalidArgumentException) {
        throw $e; //don't handle the exception
    }
}
```

This makes your code much more readable and easier to troubleshoot as opposed to a lot of alternative solutions.
With that said, Exceptions should be treated as unexpected functionality outside of normal processes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I'd do that :

```
<?php
    echo 'this' . PHP_EOL;
    switch(true) {
        default:
            try {
                if(rand(0,10)>5) {
                    echo 'is' . PHP_EOL;
                    break;
                }
                echo 'is not' . PHP_EOL;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // error_log($e->getMessage());
            }
    }
    echo 'fun !';
```

:-)

Answer (score -1):

Personally I like to exit try/catch statements by using a

```
throw new MyException("optional message", MyException::ERROR_SUCCESS);
```

which I obviously catch by using this code (inside the `catch()` statement)

```
catch(MyException $e) {
    switch($e->getCode()) {
       /** other cases make sense here */
       case MyException::ERROR_SQL:
           logThis("A SQL error occurred. Details: " . $e->getMessage());
       break;

       case MyException::ERROR_SUCCESS:
           logThis("Completed with success. Details: " . $e->getMessage());
       break;

       case MyException::ERROR_UNDEFINED:
       default:
       logThis("Undefined error. Details: " . $e->getMessage());
       break;
    }
}
```

`MyException` being just an extension of Exception, which also defines class constants.

Comment: Rather, intrinsic value of this entire answer is void. Distinguishing exceptions by codes makes no sense when PHP can distinguish different exceptions using multiple catch blocks. The example is too artificial and makes no sense in the real life, as all three branches do essentially the same - log the error. And it can be easily reduced to just a single branch, provided  $e->getMessage() already contains some information about error's nature. Above all, it seems you are using exceptions for the control flow, which is [anti-pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/189225/123793)

Comment: Thank you for expressing your idea.
It's called an example, a template. Nobody asked you to send your résumé with "Your Name here" as title. You can get inspired, and amend it.

This example is really good, as it shows how to extend the std Exception class, and how to make a consistent error handler, with the notorious code "0" error (i.e. ERROR_SUCCESS here), meaning "success".

Welcome to a world where other people have different ideas to you.
I too can blog about patterns and anti-patterns.
In IT there are more than one way to do (good) things. Welcome to democratic IT.

Comment: Not a good pattern to use too many error exception class extensions, if this is what you were thinking of with your cascading try/catch blocks. Rather an anti-pattern for clarity. No need to confuse humans, even if computers will follow no problems.